# How to generate a session number in clickstream data in r?

Tags: r, session

I want to add a new variable that indicates the session number of each click.

My dataset looks like this (each row represents a click):

```
      head(test)

        CustomerID UserID Page
      1          1      1    A
      2          1      1    B
      3          1      1    C
      4          1      1    D
      5          2      2    A
      6          2      2    B
```

Because the different users will create multiple clickstreams, I want to assign a session number to each click. The condition is, when the customerID is different, this will be a new session for that user.

I would want it like this:

```
           CustomerID UserID Page Session
      1           1      1    A       1
      2           1      1    B       1
      3           1      1    C       1
      4           1      1    D       1
      5           2      2    A       1
      6           2      2    B       1
      7           2      2    E       1
      8           2      2    F       1
      9           3      3    A       1
      10          3      3    B       1
      11          3      3    C       1
      12          3      3    G       1
      13          3      3    H       1
      14          3      3    I       1
      15          4      4    A       1
      16          4      4    B       1
      17          4      4    C       1
      18          4      4    D       1
      19          4      4    E       1
      20          5      5    A       1
      21          5      5    B       1
      22          6      6    A       1
      23          6      6    B       1
      24          7      1    A       2
      25          7      1    B       2
      26          8      2    A       2
      27          8      2    B       2
      28          8      2    C       2
      29          8      2    G       2
      30          8      2    H       2
```

I tried to solve it with the group_by() and mutate() command. However, I think I have to create something like an ifelse() statement to assign the right session numbers. I hope that anyone can help me out!

What I've tried:

```
      test<-test  %>%   group_by(CustomerID, UserID)   %>%   mutate(Session = )
```

Comment: Can you show a few more lines of data to understand what you meant?  From the head of the data, it is not that clear

Comment: I've added a screenshot, hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for showing more data and what will the corresponding 'Session' for those data i.e. where does the 'Session' becomes 2 from 1.  It is also better not to show as an image for copying the data

Comment: I now added a full version of how I would like to see the dataset. The Session number becomes 2 from 1 if that UserID is present, only with a different corresponding CustomerID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps (assuming that 'CustomerID' and 'UserID' are ordered)

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
     mutate(Session = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(UserID)< 0)))
#    CustomerID UserID Page Session
#1           1      1    A       1
#2           1      1    B       1
#3           1      1    C       1
#4           1      1    D       1
#5           2      2    A       1
#6           2      2    B       1
#7           2      2    E       1
#8           2      2    F       1
#9           3      3    A       1
#10          3      3    B       1
#11          3      3    C       1
#12          3      3    G       1
#13          3      3    H       1
#14          3      3    I       1
#15          4      4    A       1
#16          4      4    B       1
#17          4      4    C       1
#18          4      4    D       1
#19          4      4    E       1
#20          5      5    A       1
#21          5      5    B       1
#22          6      6    A       1
#23          6      6    B       1
#24          7      1    A       2
#25          7      1    B       2
#26          8      2    A       2
#27          8      2    B       2
#28          8      2    C       2
#29          8      2    G       2
#30          8      2    H       2
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(CustomerID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), UserID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Page = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", 
"B", "E", "F", "A", "B", "C", "G", "H", "I", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "G", "H")),
.Names = c("CustomerID", 
"UserID", "Page"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"29", "30"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you also have a solution where CustomerID and UserID does not have to be in the right order?

Comment: @L.Molenaar  In that case, we can order it i.e `test %>% arrange(CustomerID, UserID) %>%  mutate(Session = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(UserID)< 0)))`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I already did that myself, and it works now perfectly.